# Scala exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, fromfile

Below is my Scala code:

```
import scala.io.Source

case class TempData(day:Int , DayOfYear:Int , month:Int , year:Int ,
                    precip:Double , snow:Double , tave:Double, tmax:Double, tmin:Double)
object TempData {
 def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit ={
   val source = Source.fromFile("C:///DataResearch/SparkScala/MN212142_9392.csv")
   val lines = source.getLines().drop(1)
   val data= lines.map{ line =>
     val p = line.split(",")
     TempData(p(0).toInt , p(1).toInt, p(2).toInt, p(4).toInt
     , p(5).toDouble, p(6).toDouble , p(7).toDouble, p(8).toDouble,p(9).toDouble)
   }.toArray
   source.close()
   data.take(5).foreach(println)
 }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=2298:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\ScalaSpark\target\scala-2.11\classes;C:\Users\Dell\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.12.jar TempData
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DataResearch\SparkScala\MN212142_9392.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
    at TempData$.main(TempData.scala:7)
    at TempData.main(TempData.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My file(MN212142_9392.csv) is in C drive inside folder DataResearch and SparkScala. I have tried all possible changes but nothing of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `File` class instead of `Source`.

```
new File("path")
```

It should solve your problem :)

Or use class `Files` :)
Below you can find links to documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Double check your path. In my opinion better option is to use a relative path instead of absolute. Put this file in a project and try to use the relative path. Your application can't find your file :)

Edit:

In created a simple file TempData.scala which contains:

```
import scala.io.Source 

object TempData {
  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit ={
    val source = Source.fromFile("test.csv")
    val lines = source.getLines()
  }
}
```

I created file `test.csv`

I used `scalac TempData.scala` and after that `scala TempData`. Everything is okay, because you use methods in correct way. You have a problem with path. So my propose is try to use file that you put in the project and if everything is okay check your previous path :)

Comment: I am not sure about File , Source is a library in Scala (import scala.io.Source) to load file. Not sure about library for File.

Comment: Yes, but for working with files in Scala the better option is use Java classes for it :) Try, I'm sure that it's better option. Here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm you can find example how to proceed files in Java. Scala class for it is not good :)

Comment: Yes you might be right , but what if I don't want to use any java libraries..Does scala libraries will not help? and using java libray will lead me to do some more code changes since command like getLines() not working.

Comment: Why? If something is better in Java, in my opinion, we should use it. If you want to use scala library try to put this file inside project and use relative path :)

Comment: Your error is related to an incorrect path, so, first of all, you need to check path. If you have a file inside you can use a relative path. In practice is better to have a control on that :)

Comment: Does scala libraries will not help? and using java libray will lead me to do some more code changes since command like getLines() not working.

Comment: Try to use a relative path. Put this file into the project.

Comment: Yes file is in correct path , but using java library i am not able to use scala function like getLines() , map() etc..and I only want to write scala code , not wanna go into java

Comment: Okay, so please go to my comment. I'll show you an example in an edit. Give me 5 minutes

Comment: Ok so how do i find the relative path , i have put the file inside C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\ScalaSpark , still not working , do i need to put some where else?

Comment: Okay, so if you put this file inside `ScalaSpark` Please try this `Source.fromFile("MN212142_9392.csv")`

Comment: Hello , I got the issue , actually my file name was MN212142_9392.csv but it was expecting.txt extension also so now doing ("MN212142_9392.csv.txt") worked for me. this is also working :"C:///DataResearch/SparkScala/MN212142_9392.csv.txt")

Comment: Nice, so the problem is with Path :)

Comment: Thank you patryk :)

Comment: No problem, please set this question as answered 

Answer (score -1):

I have been facing issues with similar error: Find sample code which i have done:

```
  object CSVDemo extends App {
         val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\dell\\IdeaProjects\\SbtExampleProject\\project\\job_test.txt")
        for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines()) {
          val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
          println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}|${cols(3)}|${cols(4)}")
        }
```

NOTE: I had to create sample file in the project directory and when i tried to see its location i noticed that the path is created with "\" try it and see how it goes